# Assigning a number to rows/columns in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a 9x9 board for a game I am developing in Python, I have managed to output a 9x9 board using a list, however I am wanting to have numbers from 1,2,3... to be ascending for both the row and column.

At the moment, my output is:

```
/ / / / / / / / / 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
& & & & & & & & &
```

But what I am wanting is:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 / / / / / / / / / 
1 . . . . . . . . . 
2 . . . . . . . . . 
3 . . . . . . . . . 
4 . . . . . . . . . 
5 . . . . . . . . . 
6 . . . . . . . . . 
7 . . . . . . . . . 
8 & & & & & & & & &
```

I would share the code I used to create this, however I am sure its just a basic piece of code to achieve this, to print the board however, I used this piece of code:

```
    for i in board:
        for j in i:
            print(j, end=" ")
        print()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your original code a little should do the trick, and adding another print into the loop

```
print(" ", end=" ")
for idx in range(len(board[0])):
    print(idx, end=" ")
print()

for idx, i in enumerate(board):
    print(idx, end=" ")
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a variable `board` which is a `list` of `list` objects.

Then you can do the following using list comprehension:

```py
# Remove the empty string if you just want a list of length 9 in board[0]
board = [[""] + list(range(9))] + board 
board = [[i] + board[i] for i in range(9)]
```